# Displaying Unlimited Structure of Categories --> Subcategories --> etc?

Tags: php, structure, hierarchy, categories

I imagine this is a fairly common requirement for people when it comes to building any kind of application that relies on sorting and displaying data in categories - any CMS/Forums/Carts etc and I've been tearing my hair out trying to think of a way to show all categories and their children to no avail - the best I've managed is while loop within while loop (however many levels I think I may require) but this defeats the point of programming in my opinion, it needs to be effortlessly extensible.

So, given:

```
Category 1
-Sub cat
-Sub cat
--Sub sub cat
--- Sub sub cat
-- Sub sub cat
-Sub cat
Category 2
-Sub cat
-Sub cat
--Sub sub cat
---sub sub sub cat
----sub sub sub sub cat
-sub cat
Category 3
-Sub cat
```

Database fields: ID Name ParentIDS

How would you go about echoing each of the categories in their hierarchy from a database?

I'd post my code, but obviously its massive, given the long-hand way of nesting loops.

I've thought about writing bits of code that find the 'depth' of the category tree but that still isn't cutting it.. ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The structure you're talking about is essentially a tree. Iterating over a tree is relatively simple if you use recursion. I don't know what database access code you're using, but you should be able to extrapolate accordingly from the following psuedocode:

```
function iterate_tree(arr) {
    foreach (item in arr) {
        print item;
        iterate_tree(item.children);
    }
}
```

In english, that means print an item in the list, then print its children, and once all children (and their children) have printed, move on to the next item in the list.

Comment: Ah that's good... I was half way there with my nested while loops, that's just the type of logic I was aiming for, originally. Thanks. :D ...I've taken a look at the nested hierarchy mysql article and though it works, it seems very long-winded for what can be achieved by this?

Comment: I didn't read the nested set model, as I'm not at all interested in MySql. It's usually fairly easy to get parent->child or child->parent relationships using an ORM or by throwing data into a hierarchical structure and iterating over it this way. Decide which you think is nicer, and go with it.

Comment: @Chris, really what it comes down to is performance. If you've got a LOT of data in tree form, then it will benefit you spending the extra time modelling that data in an appropriate form for a database. If you need to do a lot of tree-like operations, it will benefit you also. If you have 100 or so (I picked a random number there) items in the hierarchy, then zapping all the data into code and manipulating it there is still plenty quick, but without the complexity of modelling it in a database. If you just want to display a your data, then the method I've written will do fine,

Answer (score 1):

There is a pretty good tutorial on mysql website.

http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/
Goto the `The Nested Set Model` if you want to read the interesting part

Frankly I do not think there are any other /better way to store hierearchical data.

Comment: An interesting concept, I can honestly say I would never have thought of a concept like that, I'll have a play - many thanks. :)

Comment: @Chris: if you think this answer helped you think to pick it as the answer. Cheres

Comment: I'll pick a correct answer when I've finished any follow-up queries with other authors, don't worry.

Comment: @Chris: no prolbem, I said it because you seem to be a new user. :)

Answer (score 1):

as a hint, you could use Recursion . General idea is available at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion . I.e. you write function that grabs and displays all files and folders in current folder. Then you repeatedly apply same function for each subfolder in same recursion loop. Etc etc etc.